# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Barcode", referenced from: objc-class-ref in

Tags: ios, xcode, generator, qr-code

I am trying to integrate a QR code generating library in to my App.

the QR generator library is:

https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-QR-Code-Generator

I guess I must have integrated it wrong as I am getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Barcode", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in QRViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is most likely to be causing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My problem is solved like that.
Please follow the directions:

```
TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> add your .m class  ->Build and Run
```

Answer (score 11):

You're most likely linking against a version of the library that was compiled for the device (ARMv6/v7 architecture), while trying to compile for the simulator (i386 architecture). Try running on a device instead.

If running it on a device doesn't work either, then you may not be linking against the library at all, and you should verify that you see the library in your project's "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase.

Comment: awesome man !! really.. "Adding library explicitly to Link binary with libraries" is the key point.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my issue by first changing the target to a library and pressed "CMD + B", which will build the all the library file. Then changing back to main target to compile and run on the device.

Note: I am using cocoapods and also have my own custom dynamic library in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by going to Xcode Build settings and in Architecture changed the standard architecture to :-

$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)

Answer (score 0):

Clean your DerivedData folder, this helps me

```
mv ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData.old
```